# TFS 2012 -attach a collection not properly detached

Tags: tfs

I have a backup of a 2012 TFS collection.  I am new to TFS, so I did not properly detach it.  For reasons I don't want to detail out... I can't get a detached backup.
So, now I'm on a new server with a new instance of TFS 2012 and I can't figure out how to "detach" the collection so that I can re-attach it.  Are there any options?  I can't use the TFSConfig recover command because it's been deprecated and is not available in TFS 2012.

Please help!

Comment: I now have the same problem - did you ever find a resolution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think TFSConfig is depreciated.  It should be available in TFS 2015 and TFS 2012.  You have both the "repair" and "diagnose" tfsConfig commands.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use `administration console of TFS` in order to attach or detach your collection. select `Team Project Collection`